# Error PHP-mysql(PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo una duda, tengo esta clase:

```
<?php
class DB{
//Función para conectar con la base de datos
public static function ejecutaConsulta($sql) {
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $dbname = "vehiculos";
    $usuario = "root";
    $contrasena = "";
    try {
        $opc = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$dbname";
        $dwes = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contrasena, $opc);
        $dwes->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $resultado = $dwes->query($sql);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Se ha producido un error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $resultado;
}

//Función para obtener los coches
public static function obtieneCoches(){
    $sql = "SELECT coche.bastidor, coche.marca, coche.descripcion, coche.tipo, tipo.nombre FROM coche, tipo WHERE coche.tipo = tipo.cod";
    $resultado = self::ejecutaConsulta($sql);
    $coches = array();
    if($resultado){
        // Añadimos un elemento por cada pedido leido
        $row = $resultado->fetch_object();
        while ($row != null){
            $coches[] = $row;
            $row = $resultado->fetch_object();
        }
    }
    return $coches;
}}?>
```

Como podeis ver saco datos de dos tablas distintas y al recogerlos intento guardarlos como un array de objetos, pero al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_object() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/DWES/xajax_DanielGomez/Ejercicio1/DB.php on line 28

¿Alguien puede ayudarme y explicarme que es lo que pasa? como podeis ver en PHP y mysql soy nuevo.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano

Comment: Cerrando como error tipográfico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `$resultado` es un objeto del tipo [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php) y el método que buscas utilizar no se llama `fetch_object`, sino que el nombre correcto es [`fetchObject`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchobject.php)

### Solución:

Modificar el método `obtieneCoches` de la siguiente forma:

```
...
public static function obtieneCoches(){
    $sql = "SELECT coche.bastidor, coche.marca, coche.descripcion, coche.tipo, tipo.nombre 
    FROM coche, tipo WHERE coche.tipo = tipo.cod";
    $resultado = self::ejecutaConsulta($sql);
    $coches = array();
    if($resultado){

        // Añadimos un elemento por cada pedido leido
        $row = $resultado->fetchObject();
        while ($row != null){
            $coches[] = $row;
            $row = $resultado->fetchObject();
        }
    }
    return $coches;
}
...
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió tu respuesta, ademas tuve que cambiar el array $coche por que el $row ya es directamente un array así que en el return meto directamente $row

Comment: Pero PDO tiene métodos para almacenar los resultados **directamente en un array**, por ejemplo [FETCH_ASSOC](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) por lo que toda la parte del while es reinventar la rueda... Así mismo, el `while ($row != null){` es redundante, la existencia de datos ya fue evaluada antes en `if($resultado){` Sería algo así: `$result = $stmt->execute($sql);
if ($result) { $datos   = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ... }` y no tienes que hacer nada más, tienes un array en `$datos` listo para leer.

Comment: @A.Cedano, la verdad que no preste mucha atención a lo que hace el código. Hay varios detalles en el código: 1. No debería ser redundante el `if($resultado)` a lo sumo lo correcto sería hacer un `if($resultado->rowCount())`. 2. La consulta en si se puede optimizar usando `INNER/LEFT JOIN`. 3. El OP recién en comentario aclaro que quería un `array de arrays` y no un `array de objects`.

Comment: No. En PDO la mejor forma de evaluar la existencia de datos es preguntando por los datos mismos, ya que si no hay datos la variable que ejecuta la consulta devuelve `false`. Con respecto a eso hay un articulo muy interesante en [PHP Delusions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count). Lamentablemente lo más usado es row count, pero no es lo más adecuado y no es siempre seguro.